# Adding a photo to the left and 3 to the side on the right

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble aligning my photo to the way I want it

I am trying to build a code where I can have a big photo to the left, and then three small pictures at the right(while both of them are aligned at the center) but the three small images end up going to the bottom

and this is the CSS

```css
.topnews{
 

}

.featurednews {
 text-align: center;
 left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

.featurednews img { 

  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 10px;  
  border: 1px solid #233988; 
  position: ralative;
   left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

.otherfeaturednews{
 text-align: center;
}

.otherfeaturednews img{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 6px;
  position: relative;
  float: center;
}
```

```html
<pre>
<code>
<html>
<div class="topnews">
<div class="featurednews"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="random image"></div>
<div class="otherfeaturednews"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="image at the side">
<div class="otherfeaturednews"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="image at the side">
<div class="otherfeaturednews"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" alt="image at the side">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

There should be one large photo on the left-center and three small pictures at the right-center of the page. Please help. I have tried soo many methods, but it just doesn't work.

this is how it shows
[What I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhXhO.png)

this is how it should look like.
[how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G52o7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your divs are all messy. Then should have added a display flex to the topnews div to place each separate div containers side by side

```css
.topnews{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 450px;
}

.featurednews {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%; 
}

.featurednews img { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.otherfeaturednews{
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%; 
}
.otherfeaturednews .otherfeaturednewsimages{
    height: 150px;;
    margin: 10px;
}
.otherfeaturednewsimages img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<div class="topnews">
    <div class="featurednews"><img
            src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
            alt="random image">
    </div>
    <div class="otherfeaturednews">
       
        <div class="otherfeaturednewsimages">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
            alt="image at the side">
           </div>
           <div class="otherfeaturednewsimages">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
            alt="image at the side">
           </div>
           <div class="otherfeaturednewsimages">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1402787/pexels-photo-1402787.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"
            alt="image at the side">
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you soo much. I see what I did and this will be a valuable lesson. I noticed though that i cant move it to center. do you know why that is?

Comment: which do you want to move to center? The left image or the right group of images?

Comment: I figured it out. thanks though. I just had to adjust the position in the topnews div.